# print elements from multiple lists by index with jq

Tags: bash, jq

I have a json with 3 equal lists:

```
{
    "value": {
        "list1": [
            "el11",
            "el12",
            "el13",
            "el14"
        ],
        "list2": [
            "el21",
            "el22",
            "el23",
            "el24"
        ],
        "list3": [
            "el31",
            "el32",
            "el33",
            "el34"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to extract from each list the elements with the same index:

```
el11 el21 el31
...
el13 el23 el33
```

Ideally those need to be exported as ENV values. But I just want to know if it's possible to do that with jq. And how.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `transpose` function for this. For example,

```
$ jq -r '[.value[]] | transpose[] | join (" ")' tmp.json
el11 el21 el31
el12 el22 el32
el13 el23 el33
el14 el24 el34
```